# Incorrect syntax error after converting PLSQL to TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I converted Oracle PLSQL code to TSQL. When I test the query I get Incorrect syntax near keyword 'ORDER' error. I am using multiple unions in the FROM statement. If I remove the ORDER BY statement the check returns Incorrect syntax error near ')'. I have included the entire converted TSQL below in hope a second pair of eyes will see the error. I am sure there are better ways of doing this, but I inherited this midway through a conversion form Oracle 11g to SQL 2012. Any help in getting around the error would be appreciated. Here is the entire statement:

```
SELECT casenumber,partynumber,ptyname,connection1,connection2,connection3,connection4,connection5,CASE WHEN LTrim(appointtype) IN ('OSA','NOA','PRO') THEN '' ELSE CAST(barnumber AS char) END AS barnumber,
 appointtype,attyname,address1,address2,city,state,zipcode,zipfour,phone,emailaddress,oralargument,timely,prisonid,appear, vacstart, vacend, vacstart1, vacend1, vacstart2, vacend2, vacstart3, vacend3, 
 vacstart4, vacend4, vacstart5, vacend5, vacstart6, vacend6, vacstart7, vacend7, vacstart8, vacend8, vacstart9, vacend9, vacstart10,vacend10,vacstart11,vacend11,vacstart12,vacend12,vacstart13,vacend13,
 vacstart14,vacend14,altaddr1,altaddr2,altcity,altstate,altzip,altzipfour, descr,eserv_address1,eserv_address2  
from (SELECT p.casenumber, p.partynumber,p.ptyname,connection1,connection2,connection3,connection4,connection5,1 AS Attorney_order,barnumber1 AS  barnumber ,appointtype1 AS appointtype, 
      CASE WHEN LTrim(RTrim(appointtype1))='OSA' THEN osaname ELSE attyname END AS attyname, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.address1 WHEN appointtype1='OSA' THEN osa.address1 ELSE addr1 END AS Address1,
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.address2 WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1))='OSA' THEN osa.address2 ELSE addr2 END AS Address2, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN z2.city WHEN appointtype1='OSA' THEN z3.city ELSE z1.city END AS CITY, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN z2.state WHEN appointtype1='OSA' THEN z3.state ELSE z1.state END AS STATE, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.zipcode WHEN appointtype1='OSA' THEN osa.zipcode ELSE a.zipcode END AS ZIPCODE, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.zipfour WHEN appointtype1='OSA' THEN osa.zipfour ELSE a.zipfour END AS ZIPFOUR, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN CONCAT(IIF(d.phonearea is NOT NULL, CONCAT(d.phonearea,'/'),''),'',SUBSTRING(CAST(d.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),1,3),'-',RIGHT(CAST(d.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),4))  
   WHEN appointtype1='OSA' THEN CONCAT(IIF(osa.phonearea is NOT NULL, CONCAT(osa.phonearea,'/'),''),'',SUBSTRING(CAST(osa.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),1,3),'-',RIGHT(CAST(osa.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),4))   
   --CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN ISNULL(d.phonearea,CAST(d.phonearea AS char)+'/','')+' '+SubString(CAST(d.phonenbr AS char),1,3)+'-'+SubString(d.phonenbr,-4)  
   --WHEN appointtype1='OSA' THEN ISNULL(osa.phonearea,CAST(osa.phonearea AS char)+'/','')+' '+SubString(CAST(osa.phonenbr AS char),1,3)+'-'+SubString(osa.phonenbr,-4) 
     --ELSE ISNULL(a.areacode,CAST(a.areacode AS char)+'/','')+' '+SubString(CAST(a.phonenbr AS char),1,3)+'-'+SubString(a.phonenbr,-4)  END AS phone, 
     ELSE CONCAT(IIF(a.phonearea is NOT NULL, CONCAT(a.phonearea,'/'),''),'',SUBSTRING(CAST(a.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),1,3),'-',RIGHT(CAST(a.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),4))  END AS phone, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.emailaddress WHEN appointtype1='OSA' THEN osa.emailaddress ELSE a.emailaddress END AS EMAILADDRESS, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.eserv_address1 WHEN appointtype1='OSA' THEN osa.eserv_address1 ELSE a.eserv_address1 END AS eserv_address1, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.eserv_address2 WHEN appointtype1='OSA' THEN osa.eserv_address2 ELSE a.eserv_address2 END AS eserv_address2, 
   oralargument,timely,prisonid,appear1 AS appear, vacstart, vacend, vacstart1, vacend1 ,vacstart2 , vacend2 , vacstart3, vacend3,vacstart4,vacend4 ,vacstart5 ,vacend5,vacstart6 ,vacend6, 
   vacstart7 ,vacend7, vacstart8 ,vacend8,vacstart9 ,vacend9, vacstart10,vacend10,vacstart11,vacend11,vacstart12,vacend12,vacstart13,vacend13,vacstart14,vacend14,altaddr1,altaddr2,
   z5.city AS altcity, z5.state AS altstate,altzip,altzipfour, descr 
   from parties  p left JOIN attorneys a ON p.barnumber1=a.attynbr 
     left JOIN address d ON p.casenumber=d.casenumber AND p.partynumber=d.partynumber AND p.courtid=d.courtid AND p.caseyear=d.caseyear AND ISNULL(p.barnumber1,0)=0 
  left join outstateaddr osa ON p.casenumber=osa.casenumber AND p.courtid=osa.courtid AND p.caseyear=osa.caseyear AND p.partynumber=osa.partynumber and p.appointtype1='OSA' AND partyattyseq=1 
  left JOIN zipcodes z1 ON a.zipcode=z1.zipcode left JOIN zipcodes z2 ON d.zipcode=z2.zipcode left JOIN zipcodes z3 ON osa.zipcode=z3.zipcode left JOIN zipcodes z5 ON a.altzip=z5.zipcode 
  left join events on a.status = events.tablecode and events.tableid = 0509 WHERE p.casenumber=332755 AND p.courtid=84
UNION 
SELECT p.casenumber, p.partynumber,p.ptyname, connection1,connection2,connection3,connection4,connection5,2 AS Attorney_order,barnumber2 AS  barnumber ,appointtype2 AS appointtype, 
    CASE WHEN LTrim(RTrim(appointtype2))='OSA' THEN osaname ELSE attyname END AS attyname, 
 CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype2)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.address1 WHEN appointtype2='OSA' THEN osa.address1 ELSE addr1 END AS Address1,
 CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype2)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.address2 WHEN appointtype2='OSA' THEN osa.address2 ELSE addr2 END AS Address2, 
 CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype2)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN z2.city WHEN appointtype2='OSA' THEN z3.city ELSE z1.city END AS CITY, 
 CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype2)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN z2.state WHEN appointtype2='OSA' THEN z3.state ELSE z1.state END AS STATE, 
 CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype2)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.zipcode WHEN appointtype2='OSA' THEN osa.zipcode ELSE a.zipcode END AS ZIPCODE, 
 CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype2)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.zipfour WHEN appointtype2='OSA' THEN osa.zipfour ELSE a.zipfour END AS ZIPFOUR, 
 CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype2)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN CONCAT(IIF(d.phonearea is NOT NULL, CONCAT(d.phonearea,'/'),''),'',SUBSTRING(CAST(d.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),1,3),'-',RIGHT(CAST(d.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),4))  
    WHEN appointtype2='OSA' THEN CONCAT(IIF(osa.phonearea is NOT NULL, CONCAT(osa.phonearea,'/'),''),'',SUBSTRING(CAST(osa.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),1,3),'-',RIGHT(CAST(osa.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),4))   
     ELSE CONCAT(IIF(a.phonearea is NOT NULL, CONCAT(a.phonearea,'/'),''),'',SUBSTRING(CAST(a.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),1,3),'-',RIGHT(CAST(a.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),4))  END AS phone, 
 --CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype2)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN ISNULL(d.phonearea,CAST(d.phonearea AS char)+'/','')+' '+SubString(CAST(d.phonenbr AS char),1,3)+'-'+SubString(d.phonenbr,-4) 
 --  WHEN appointtype2='OSA' THEN ISNULL(osa.phonearea,CAST(osa.phonearea AS char)+'/','')+' '+SubString(CAST(osa.phonenbr AS char),1,3)+'-'+SubString(osa.phonenbr,-4) 
 --  ELSE ISNULL(a.areacode,CAST(a.areacode AS char)+'/','')+' '+SubString(CAST(a.phonenbr AS char),1,3)+'-'+SubString(a.phonenbr,-4) END AS phone, 
 CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype2)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.emailaddress WHEN appointtype2='OSA' THEN osa.emailaddress ELSE a.emailaddress END AS EMAILADDRESS, 
 CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype2)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.eserv_address1 WHEN appointtype2='OSA' THEN osa.eserv_address1 ELSE a.eserv_address1 END AS eserv_address1, 
 CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype2)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.eserv_address2 WHEN appointtype2='OSA' THEN osa.eserv_address2 ELSE a.eserv_address2 END AS eserv_address2, 
 oralargument,timely,prisonid ,appear2 AS appear, vacstart, vacend, vacstart1, vacend1 ,vacstart2 , vacend2 , vacstart3, vacend3,vacstart4,vacend4 ,vacstart5 ,vacend5,vacstart6 ,vacend6, 
 vacstart7 ,vacend7, vacstart8 ,vacend8,vacstart9 ,vacend9, vacstart10,vacend10, vacstart11,vacend11,vacstart12,vacend12,vacstart13,vacend13,vacstart14,vacend14,altaddr1,altaddr2,
 z5.city AS altcity, z5.state AS altstate,altzip,altzipfour, descr 
from parties  p left JOIN attorneys a ON p.barnumber2=a.attynbr 
  left JOIN address d ON p.casenumber=d.casenumber AND p.partynumber=d.partynumber AND p.courtid=d.courtid AND p.caseyear=d.caseyear AND ISNULL(p.barnumber2,0)=0 
  left join outstateaddr osa ON p.casenumber=osa.casenumber AND p.courtid=osa.courtid AND p.caseyear=osa.caseyear AND p.partynumber=osa.partynumber AND p.appointtype2='OSA' AND partyattyseq=2 
  left JOIN zipcodes z1 ON a.zipcode=z1.zipcode left JOIN zipcodes z2 ON d.zipcode=z2.zipcode left JOIN zipcodes z3 ON osa.zipcode=z3.zipcode  
  left JOIN zipcodes z5 ON a.altzip=z5.zipcode left join events on a.status = events.tablecode and events.tableid = 0509  WHERE p.casenumber=332755 AND appointtype2 IS NOT null AND p.courtid=84
UNION 
SELECT p.casenumber, p.partynumber,p.ptyname, connection1,connection2,connection3,connection4,connection5,3 AS Attorney_order,barnumber3 AS  barnumber ,appointtype3 AS appointtype, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(RTrim(appointtype3))='OSA' THEN osaname ELSE attyname END AS attyname, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype3)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.address1 WHEN appointtype3='OSA' THEN osa.address1 ELSE addr1 END AS Address1, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype3)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.address2 WHEN appointtype3='OSA' THEN osa.address2 ELSE addr2 END AS Address2, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype3)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN z2.city WHEN appointtype3='OSA' THEN z3.city ELSE z1.city END AS CITY, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype3)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN z2.state WHEN appointtype3='OSA' THEN z3.state ELSE z1.state END AS STATE, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype3)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.zipcode WHEN appointtype3='OSA' THEN osa.zipcode ELSE a.zipcode END AS ZIPCODE, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype3)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.zipfour WHEN appointtype3='OSA' THEN osa.zipfour ELSE a.zipfour END AS ZIPFOUR, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype3)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN CONCAT(IIF(d.phonearea is NOT NULL, CONCAT(d.phonearea,'/'),''),'',SUBSTRING(CAST(d.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),1,3),'-',RIGHT(CAST(d.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),4))  
   WHEN appointtype3='OSA' THEN CONCAT(IIF(osa.phonearea is NOT NULL, CONCAT(osa.phonearea,'/'),''),'',SUBSTRING(CAST(osa.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),1,3),'-',RIGHT(CAST(osa.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),4))   
     ELSE CONCAT(IIF(a.phonearea is NOT NULL, CONCAT(a.phonearea,'/'),''),'',SUBSTRING(CAST(a.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),1,3),'-',RIGHT(CAST(a.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),4))  END AS phone, 
 --CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype3)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN ISNULL(d.phonearea,CAST(d.phonearea AS char)+'/','')+' '+SubString(CAST(d.phonenbr AS char),1,3)+'-'+SubString(d.phonenbr,-4) 
 --WHEN appointtype3='OSA' THEN ISNULL(osa.phonearea,CAST(osa.phonearea AS char)+'/','')+' '+SubString(CAST(osa.phonenbr AS char),1,3)+'-'+SubString(osa.phonenbr,-4) 
 -- ELSE ISNULL(a.areacode,CAST(a.areacode AS char)+'/','')+' '+SubString(CAST(a.phonenbr AS char),1,3)||'-'||SubString(a.phonenbr,-4) END AS phone, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype3)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.emailaddress WHEN appointtype3='OSA' THEN osa.emailaddress ELSE a.emailaddress END AS EMAILADDRESS, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype3)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.eserv_address1 WHEN appointtype3='OSA' THEN osa.eserv_address1 ELSE a.eserv_address1 END AS eserv_address1, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype3)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.eserv_address2 WHEN appointtype3='OSA' THEN osa.eserv_address2 ELSE a.eserv_address2 END AS eserv_address2,  
   oralargument,timely,prisonid,appear3 AS appear, vacstart, vacend, vacstart1, vacend1 ,vacstart2 , vacend2 , vacstart3, vacend3,vacstart4,vacend4 ,vacstart5 ,vacend5,vacstart6 ,vacend6, 
   vacstart7 ,vacend7, vacstart8 ,vacend8,vacstart9 ,vacend9,  vacstart10 ,vacend10, vacstart11 ,vacend11, vacstart12 ,vacend12, vacstart13,vacend13, vacstart14, vacend14,altaddr1,altaddr2,
   z5.city AS altcity, z5.state AS altstate,altzip,altzipfour, descr  
  from parties  p  left JOIN attorneys a ON p.barnumber3=a.attynbr 
    left JOIN address d ON p.casenumber=d.casenumber AND p.partynumber=d.partynumber AND p.courtid=d.courtid AND p.caseyear=d.caseyear AND ISNULL(p.barnumber3,0)=0  
 left join outstateaddr osa ON p.casenumber=osa.casenumber AND p.courtid=osa.courtid AND p.caseyear=osa.caseyear AND p.partynumber=osa.partynumber AND p.appointtype3='OSA' AND partyattyseq=3 
 left JOIN zipcodes z1 ON a.zipcode=z1.zipcode left JOIN zipcodes z2 ON d.zipcode=z2.zipcode left JOIN zipcodes z3 ON osa.zipcode=z3.zipcode 
 left JOIN zipcodes z5 ON a.altzip=z5.zipcode left join events on a.status = events.tablecode and events.tableid = 0509  
 WHERE p.casenumber=332755 AND appointtype3 IS NOT null AND p.courtid=84
UNION 
SELECT p.casenumber, p.partynumber,p.ptyname, connection1,connection2,connection3,connection4,connection5,4 AS Attorney_order,barnumber2 AS  barnumber ,appointtype4 AS appointtype, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(RTrim(appointtype4))='OSA' THEN osaname ELSE attyname END AS attyname, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype4)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.address1 WHEN appointtype4='OSA' THEN osa.address1 ELSE addr1 END AS Address1, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype4)) in ('PRO','NOA')  THEN d.address2 WHEN appointtype4='OSA' THEN osa.address2 ELSE addr2 END AS Address2, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype4)) in ('PRO','NOA')  THEN z2.city WHEN appointtype4='OSA' THEN z3.city ELSE z1.city END AS CITY, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype4)) in ('PRO','NOA')  THEN z2.state WHEN appointtype4='OSA' THEN z3.state ELSE z1.state END AS STATE, CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype4)) in ('PRO','NOA')  
     THEN d.zipcode WHEN appointtype4='OSA' THEN osa.zipcode ELSE a.zipcode END AS ZIPCODE, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype4)) in ('PRO','NOA')  THEN d.zipfour WHEN appointtype4='OSA' THEN osa.zipfour ELSE a.zipfour END AS ZIPFOUR, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype4)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN CONCAT(IIF(d.phonearea is NOT NULL, CONCAT(d.phonearea,'/'),''),'',SUBSTRING(CAST(d.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),1,3),'-',RIGHT(CAST(d.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),4))  
   WHEN appointtype4='OSA' THEN CONCAT(IIF(osa.phonearea is NOT NULL, CONCAT(osa.phonearea,'/'),''),'',SUBSTRING(CAST(osa.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),1,3),'-',RIGHT(CAST(osa.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),4))   
     ELSE CONCAT(IIF(a.phonearea is NOT NULL, CONCAT(a.phonearea,'/'),''),'',SUBSTRING(CAST(a.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),1,3),'-',RIGHT(CAST(a.phonenbr as VARCHAR(100)),4))  END AS phone, 
   --CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype4)) in ('PRO','NOA')  THEN ISNULL(d.phonearea,CAST(d.phonearea AS char)+'/','')+' '+SubString(CAST(d.phonenbr AS char),1,3)+'-'+SubString(d.phonenbr,-4)  
    --WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype4))='OSA'  THEN ISNULL(osa.phonearea,CAST(osa.phonearea AS char)+'/','')+' '+SubString(CAST(osa.phonenbr AS char),1,3)+'-'+SubString(osa.phonenbr,-4) 
    --ELSE ISNULL(a.areacode,CAST(a.areacode AS char)+'/','')+' '+SubString(CAST(a.phonenbr AS char),1,3)+'-'+SubString(a.phonenbr,-4) END AS phone, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype4)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.emailaddress WHEN appointtype4='OSA' THEN osa.emailaddress ELSE a.emailaddress END AS EMAILADDRESS, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype4)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.eserv_address1 WHEN appointtype4='OSA' THEN osa.eserv_address1 ELSE a.eserv_address1 END AS eserv_address1, 
   CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype4)) in ('PRO','NOA') THEN d.eserv_address2 WHEN appointtype4='OSA' THEN osa.eserv_address2 ELSE a.eserv_address2 END AS eserv_address2, oralargument,timely,
   prisonid,appear4 AS appear, vacstart, vacend, vacstart1, vacend1 ,vacstart2 , vacend2 , vacstart3, vacend3,vacstart4,vacend4 ,vacstart5 ,vacend5,vacstart6 ,vacend6, vacstart7 ,vacend7, vacstart8 ,
   vacend8,vacstart9 ,vacend9,  vacstart10,vacend10,vacstart11,vacend11,vacstart12,vacend12,vacstart13,vacend13,vacstart14,vacend14, altaddr1,altaddr2,z5.city AS altcity, 
   z5.state AS altstate,altzip,altzipfour, descr 
 from parties p left JOIN attorneys a ON p.barnumber4=a.attynbr 
 left JOIN address d ON p.casenumber=d.casenumber AND p.partynumber=d.partynumber AND p.courtid=d.courtid AND p.caseyear=d.caseyear AND ISNULL(p.barnumber4,0)=0 
 left join outstateaddr osa ON p.casenumber=osa.casenumber AND p.courtid=osa.courtid AND p.caseyear=osa.caseyear AND p.partynumber=osa.partynumber AND p.appointtype4='OSA' AND partyattyseq=4 
 left JOIN zipcodes z1 ON a.zipcode=z1.zipcode left JOIN zipcodes z2 ON d.zipcode=z2.zipcode left JOIN zipcodes z3 ON osa.zipcode=z3.zipcode left JOIN zipcodes z5 ON a.altzip=z5.zipcode 
 left join events on a.status = events.tablecode and events.tableid = 0509 WHERE p.casenumber=332755 AND p.courtid=84 AND appointtype4 IS NOT NULL)
**ORDER BY casenumber,partynumber,attorney_order**
```

Comment: This looks scary :=)

Comment: Someone with the rep to edit this, please format.

Comment: Isnt worthy read that.   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You may try http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm, to see if the format is correct or if missing a parenthesis. Also split the problem in smaller pieces so you can find the error more easily. Eat the elephant piece by piece, not all at the same time.

Comment: Replace `ORDER BY...` with `testtable ORDER BY...`. Looks like the subquery is missing an alias

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) ORDER BY ...` you must name your derived table.

Before the `ORDER BY` you must set a `AS tbl` after the closing paranthesis.

So the full query is like this

```
 SELECT col1, col2, ... 
 FROM 
 (SELECT Something) AS tbl --any alias
 ORDER BY col1
```